# Trying to set seed on tensorflow to make replicable runs on an LSTM?

Tags: lstm, tensorflow

I have seen other questions regarding reproducibility of deep learning models. Specifically in tensorflow the main ways are by setting `tf.random.set_random_seed()`

In the following example code, an LSTM is defined in tensorflow and then trained on the MNIST dataset. I am trying to set random seeds so the initialization of the network is the same (same weights and bias) and trying to get the same loss and accuracy results after the same number of training iterations.

Although I set seeds for initialization of weights and bias, and then set random seed by tensorflow within the session loop, I still get different losses and accuracies on the same iterations on different initializations of the network.

What is the source of stochasticity in this code that is boicoting the attempts to seed every random event?

```
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn

# Import MNIST data
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

# Training Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_steps = 100
batch_size = 128
display_step = 200

# Network Parameters
num_input = 28 # MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)
timesteps = 28 # timesteps
num_hidden = 128 # hidden layer num of features
num_classes = 10 # MNIST total classes (0-9 digits)

# tf Graph input
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, timesteps, num_input])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, num_classes])

# Define weights
weights = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden, num_classes], seed=1))
}
biases = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_classes], seed=1))
}


def RNN(x, weights, biases):
    x = tf.unstack(x, timesteps, 1)
    lstm_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_hidden, forget_bias=1.0)
    outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
    return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out']) + biases['out']

logits = RNN(X, weights, biases)
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

# Define loss and optimizer
loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    logits=logits, labels=Y))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op)

# Evaluate model (with test logits, for dropout to be disabled)
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

# Initialize the variables (i.e. assign their default value)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()


# Start training
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.set_random_seed(1)
    # Run the initializer
    sess.run(init)

    for step in range(1, training_steps+1):
        batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
        # Reshape data to get 28 seq of 28 elements
        batch_x = batch_x.reshape((batch_size, timesteps, num_input))
        # Run optimization op (backprop)
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y: batch_y})
        if step % display_step == 0 or step == 1:
            # Calculate batch loss and accuracy
            loss, acc = sess.run([loss_op, accuracy], feed_dict={X: batch_x,
                                                                 Y: batch_y})
            print("Step " + str(step) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + \
                  "{:.4f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                  "{:.3f}".format(acc))

    print("Optimization Finished!")

    # Calculate accuracy for 128 mnist test images
    test_len = 128
    test_data = mnist.test.images[:test_len].reshape((-1, timesteps, num_input))
    test_label = mnist.test.labels[:test_len]
    print("Testing Accuracy:", \
    sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: test_data, Y: test_label}))
```